# IronPython compiled exe still needs py modules

Tags: ironpython

I am compiling IronPython code using ipyc.exe with the following command:
ipyc /main:File1.py File2.py File3.py File4.py /target:winexe

and my exe runs properly! I put the Microsoft and IronPython DLLs and the Python .py modules in the same folder as my source code before compiling.

But now, when I try to run my executable, I still have to have the Python library files in the same folder for it to find the modules and not throw an error. Why can't it find them?

In the Windows path I have:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib
My PYPATH also has these locations.

I also tried adding
    clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("IronPython.Modules.dll")
and removing the Python Import statements, but I still get "No module named..." (and this also messes up Intelisense when I edit the code in VB).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't need to use the IronPython.Modules.dll if it can find the Python libraries. However, it isn't finding them even though it does when run non-compiled.

Comment: If I add:import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7") before compiling, it works. But I can't guarantee the install location of Python on other PCs, and it seems strange to need to explicitely add this since PYTHONPATH is already set.